# preventing a hidden form div from auto hiding when submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

By using the `.hide()` and `.show()` jquery methods i was able to hide and make visible a sign up form on my website.

After filling the sign up form and submit button is pressed the form submits and automatically hides back, because of this auto hiding the user is unable to see any error message when the submit button is clicked.

The error messages can be seen when the user clicks on the sign up button again.

I want someone to please tell me how to prevent this sign up form from auto hiding when the submit button is clicked so that the user can be able to see the errors without clicking on the sign up button the second time.

My validation is written in `php`. ** Thanks in advance.

Comment: upload your code to snippet so that it could be easy to solve

Comment: This seems like a simple problem, but it would be impossible to address without showing code.

Comment: Are you refresh the page after form submit.

Comment: us type button not submit or use e.preventDefault()

Comment: If your error container, has 'display:none'  css   or hidden="hidden" property at start and you are changing this by show() and hide(), after the form submission this container will be restarted. You should show or hide it again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the problem you are having is because the form is submitting when the submit button is clicked.

A trick I like to do: I don't use input type submit but instead use a generic button and submit the form once validation has passed, this will stop the form from submitting when submit is clicked and allow you to show any errors:

```
<button id="submit_form" class="submit">Submit</submit>
```

Hope it helps.

Of course a code sample would better help me understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without code : From My understanding , You can do it in two ways.

> First Ajax :

```
$('#submitButton').click(function (e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: url, //action
         data: form.serialize(),
         success: function (html) {
             // if html get error then show at above the form as yourt wish
          }
       });
      });
```

> If you submit form and get back at same page with error in $error varible. Then print your in contact form . and you can show your popup by script code and php

```
    if(isset($error)){
     ?> <script>
       $('#signupform').modal('show'); // if your form in bootstrap modal Otherwise
  $('#signupform').show(); 

</script> <?php    
}
```

Hope it will helpfull for you.